# How to mock httpclient

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, moq

I am new in TDD can you please write test case using moq for following code -

```
public async Task<Model> GetAssetDeliveryRecordForId(string id)
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync($"api/getdata?id={id}");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Model>();
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try some research and writing the unit test on your own and ask question here is you face any issue in that?

Answer (score 16):

You can use `Moq` to mock it.

> **Using Moq to do that for you**
>
> Now, you probably don’t want to create a new class for each response.
>   You could write a helper class for tests which you can prime with
>   whatever response you might want, but that is probably not flexible
>   enough.
>
> Moq is a popular .NET library that helps mocking objects for testing.
>   In essence it uses reflection and expressions to dynamically generate
>   the mocks at runtime during your tests, based on specifications you
>   declare using a fluent API.
>
> Now, there is a slight issue here, too. As you noticed, the SendAsync
>   method on the abstract HttpMessageHandler class is protected. The
>   caveat: Moq can’t auto-implement protected methods as easy as it does
>   with interfaces or public methods. Reason being, that the fluent API
>   uses expressions on the mocked Type, and this can’t offer private or
>   protected members, as you access the class from the outside here. So,
>   we have to use some more advanced features of Moq to mock out our
>   protected method here.
>
> Moq, therefore, has an API for that. You do use Moq. Protected; in your
>   using clauses, and then you can go on on your Moq with the
>   .Protected() method. This gives you some additional methods on the
>   Moq, where you can access the protected members using their names.
>
> A complete test of a class using a HttpClient using Moq would look
>   like this:

```
// ARRANGE
var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
handlerMock
   .Protected()
   // Setup the PROTECTED method to mock
   .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
      "SendAsync",
      ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
      ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
   )
   // prepare the expected response of the mocked http call
   .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
   {
      StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
      Content = new StringContent("[{'id':1,'value':'1'}]"),
   })
   .Verifiable();

// use real http client with mocked handler here
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object)
{
   BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.com/"),
};

var subjectUnderTest = new MyTestClass(httpClient);

// ACT
var result = await subjectUnderTest
   .GetSomethingRemoteAsync('api/test/whatever');

// ASSERT
result.Should().NotBeNull(); // this is fluent assertions here...
result.Id.Should().Be(1);

// also check the 'http' call was like we expected it
var expectedUri = new Uri("http://test.com/api/test/whatever");

handlerMock.Protected().Verify(
   "SendAsync",
   Times.Exactly(1), // we expected a single external request
   ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req =>
      req.Method == HttpMethod.Get  // we expected a GET request
      && req.RequestUri == expectedUri // to this uri
   ),
   ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
);
```

> For unit tests, you don’t mock HttpClient. Instead, you mock
>   HttpMessageHandler, put that into an HttpClient and have it return
>   whatever you want that way. If you don’t want to create s specific
>   derivation of HttpMessageHandler for each test, you can also have Moq
>   create the mocks for you automatically.

Read the whole article [here](https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/).